# Angular routing error: should only include this file once

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-routing

I am playing with [tutorial Tour of Heroes found here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html). Everything runs and looks fine. However, after I added routing from root page to dashboard and to hero's detail, I got the following error in the console:

```
Unexpected condition on http://localhost:3000/dashboard: should only include this file once
```

The error is seen after I click in the link to Dashboard.
The message is thrown from that line of code:

```
expect(!loadTimeData, 'should only include this file once');
```

in *VM1812:155*. JS version is V8 5.6.326.50. Version of Angular I am using is 4.0.0, as declared in **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
  ...
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../heroes/hero';
import { HeroService } from '../model/hero.service';

@Component ({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './html/dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css/app.css'],
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

The `/dashboard` page is linked in **app.component** template, like that:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a><!--another page, also problematic-->
  <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and route definition is defined in a module like that:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(
    [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
    ]
  ) ],
  //...
})
```

Anyone knows what this error means and why it pops up?

Comment: please post code that has your link in it and also route definition.

Comment: @banan3'14 did you solve it? What is your browser? Have the same problem with React Router

Comment: I did not solve it. My browser is Yandex 57 (it is based on Chromium, so it is basically akin to Google Chrome). I tried to open it in other browsers, but the app does not load (e.g. in Safari 5.1.7, which is not my default browser, I can see only _Loading HeroComponent content here ..._).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked with every browser and seems it applies only to Yandex browser. From my perspective, that bug needs to be sent to Yandex Support team. However, it doesn't affect end-user experience or any functionally. We can safely ignore it for now.

PS - angular application isn't working on old safari (5.1.7), use the latest one(9-10) which is available only on MacOS or any other modern browser.